# Infinite recursion (Stackoverflow) with JPA and Biderectional ManyToMany Relantionship

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, many-to-many, stack-overflow, infinite-recursion

I have a `Spring Boot 1.3.5-RELEASE` application which is using `JPA`to Relate my `USERS` to the `ROLES` with a `Bi-directional ManyToMany` relationship.

> User

```
@Table(name = "Users")
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_iid")
    @OneToMany  
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;

    //getters and setters
```

> UserRole (intermediary table)

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "user_iid", "role_iid" }))
@Entity
public class UserRole extends BaseEntity {

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull    
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;  

    //getters and setters
```

> Role

```
@Entity
public class Role extends BaseEntity {

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "role_iid")
    @OneToMany
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;

    //getters and setters
```

BaseEntity is a class with `Ids` and `Version` generator.

> Repository

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Role, String> {

    Role findByIid(@Param("iid") final String iid);
```

When I cURL a `localhost:8080/roles/search/findByIid?iid=1` I get a `StackOverflow`. If the object does not exist, the application respond fine.

I already tried `@JsonIgnore` but does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

I updated the `Spring Boot to 1.4.2-RELEASE` (which is the last) and everything worked like a charm. I think with the update it updates JPA and Hibernate and make them handle better those ManyToMany relantionships.